# What is 'the pattern' for making ASP.Net Web Forms?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know there are lots of design patterns (facade, singleton, decorator, etc...) but I'm reading about `ASP.NET MVC` and I'm about two sentences into the 'Intro' and I'm already confused.

> The ASP.NET MVC framework provides an alternative to the ASP.NET Web Forms pattern for creating Web applications.

I don't understand what that means.  I'm assuming ASP.NET MVC is going to force or encourage a Model-View-Controller pattern, but what pattern is ASP.NET?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asp.Net is **Page-Controller** pattern. The request is handled by various **events** in the code behind of the Page.

Asp.Net Mvc uses **Model-View-Controller** pattern in which request is handled by the Controller which interacts with Model and then Renders a View.

**Update:** More info about Page Controller.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html

Comment: Is the Page Controller a Microsoft pattern, or a universal pattern?

Comment: @Irish: Looks like Page Controller is not MS only pattern as it is mentioned by Martin Flower.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

Link: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/16/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-mvc-and-mvp-but.aspx

Classic ASP.NET uses the MVP pattern btw :)

It should answer your question!